# BASH -- Complex Comparisons

Tags: bash, comparison

The code is taking three variables and checking if two of them are the same but the third is different, and if this is the case then it will report that the variables make up an Isosceles Triangle
So I have arranged that if $s1s2 is true that means that $s1 is equal to $s2

```
if [ $s1s2 && $s2s3 !&& $s1s3 ] || [ $s1s2 && $s1s3 !&& $s2s3 ] || [ $s2s3 && $s1s3 !&& $s1s2 ] = true
     then isostri = True
    else isostri = false
    fi
```

I am just learning my foundation and am confused why the above code is not working. I have tried:

1. Wrapping the whole series in a superset of parentheses, as well as keeping them individual
2. I have played with the case sensitivity of the boolean designator
3. I have tried assigning booleans to the sets individually
4. I have also tried separating these OR statements into three separate IF clauses

The Shellcheck is saying:

```
    Line 1:
if [ $s1s2 && $s2s3 !&& $s1s3 ] || [ $s1s2 && $s1s3 !&& $s2s3 ] || [ $s2s3 && $s1s3 !&& $s1s2 ] = true
^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this if expression.
   ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression. Fix to allow more checks.
                    ^-- SC1072: Expected test to end here (don't wrap commands in []/[[]]). Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

And here is the entire code, with some added tweaks since starting this post:

```
read X
read Y
read Z

s1 = $X
s2 = $Y
s3 = $Z

if s1 -eq s2 
 then s1s2 = true
else s1s2 = false
fi

if s2 -eq s3
 then s2s3 = true
else s2s3 = false
fi

if s1 -eq s3
 then s1s3 = true
else s1s3 = false
fi

if [ $s1s2 && $s2s3 && $s1s3 ] = true
 then equatri = true
else equatri = false
fi

if [ [ $s1s2 -eq $s2s3 ] && [ $s1s2 -ne $s1s3 ] ] || [ [ $s1s2 -eq $s1s3 ] && [ $s1s2 -ne $s2s3 ] || [ [ $s2s3 -eq $s1s3 ] && [ $s2s3 -ne $s1s2 ] ] = true
 then isostri = true
else isostri = false
fi

if [ $s1s2 && $s2s3 && $s2s3] = false
 then scaltri = true
fi

if $equatri = true
 then 
  echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif $isostri = true
 then
  echo "ISOSCELES" 
elif $scaltri = true
 then
  echo "SCALENE"
fi
```

SOLVED! Thank you all for your help. The comments pointed out a couple flaws that I was not aware of, and the answers both helped lead me to understand that my logic was overly complex. I was trying to check two cases for truth and then verify the third case as false.. But I now see that there is an assumptive biconditional thing happening where I can ignore the third case as long as the checks flow in the correct order (from the most checks to the least) and that allows me to reduce the isosceles calculations to several comparisons of two sides each.

Here is what that jumbled mass has been reduced to:

```
read X
read Y
read Z

s1=$X
s2=$Y
s3=$Z

if [ $s1 == $s2 ] && [ $s1 == $s3 ]; then echo "EQUILATERAL"
 elif [ $s1 -eq $s2 ];                  then echo "ISOSCELES"
 elif [ $s2 -eq $s3 ];                  then echo "ISOSCELES"
 elif [ $s1 -eq $s3 ];                  then echo "ISOSCELES"
else                                        echo "SCALENE"
fi
```

Comment: I've never seen `!&&` before - what does it mean?

Comment: `[` doesn't have an `&&` (though `[[` does), let alone a `!&&` operator.

Comment: It would help to describe what you are trying to do, rather than how you are trying to fix your syntactically incorrect code.

Comment: !&& to mean NotAnd

Comment: The code is taking three variables and checking if two of them are the same but the third is different, and if this is the case then it will report that the variables make up an Isosceles Triangle

Comment: So I have arranged that if $s1s2 is true that means that $s1 is equal to $s2

Comment: Do you put literal strings `true` and `false` into your variables? `[ true ]` checks if the string `true` is non-empty, which it always is. That means that `[ false ]` is also true. `true` and `false` are not special as strings.

Comment: Maybe take a step back and show the input data; the approach that combines individual comparisons into variables is almost certainly not ideal.

Comment: Benjamin, the boolean should be a value as it is not listed in quotations, am I missing some element of how that works?

Comment: Also, please run syntax check (at least sh -n), the script-style not work well with bash - you can not have space in assignments (`s1 = $x`). Condition like `if s1 -eq s2 ` need brackets, etc.

Comment: @CyrilHouse, use unified compare, `=` is for strings, `-eq` for numbers. And not need to use `==`, `=` is enough.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Awesome, thank you! That is very helpful. I have been playing around with the different versions, and have basically been just tossing them in randomly and then switching out until it works >. <

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split the logic and make it much more readable:

```
FLAG=0
if [ "$s1" = "$s2" ] && [ "$s1" != "$s3" ]
then FLAG=1
elif [ "$s1" = "$s3" ] && [ "$s1" != "$s2" ]
then FLAG=1
elif [ "$s2" = "$s3" ] && [ "$s1" != "$s2" ]
then FLAG=1
fi
```

and then use `FLAG` to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem (identify triangle type in bash), Search for `isosceles bash`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isosceles+bash

Simple one:

```
#!/bin/bash
read a b c
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ] && [ "$b" -eq "$c" ] ; then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif [ "$a" -eq "$b" ] || [ "$b" -eq "$c" ] || [ "$c" -eq "$a" ]; then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
then
    echo "SCALENE"
fi
```